# Can't set Board Swimlane Criteria in Azure DevOps Server 2022

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-server-2022

I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2022, am Team and Project Collection Administrator, and in Project > Board > Gear > Settings > Swimlanes, when adding a Swimlane, I don't see the Add Criteria option.

Bing Chat suggests confirming version (latest), permissions (aforementioned Admin role memberships), and browser version (Edge.latest on Win 11.latest).

What am I missing?

**Additions, 2023.12.21**: Script and output below. I now am wondering whether Work Areas are in play here. My environment currently has 3 Work Areas and the script uris are not parameterized by this quality. The Swimlanes are configured only on one of the boards. I can move the Work Item to a different Work Area where there are no swimlanes at all and the output doesn't differ. Could this be the source of my problem? How would I specify the target Work Area?

```
# update-Swimlane.ps1

param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$id = $null
)

$server = "devops.huhs.harvard.edu" # The name or IP address of your Azure DevOps Server
$collection = "HUHS_IS"
$project = "TEMP-JIRA-MIGRATION"
$baseUri = "https://$server/$collection/$project/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.0"
$pat = Get-Content .\rawpat.txt -Raw # Personal Access Token
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))

$boardUri = "https://$server/$collection/$project/_apis/work/boards/Issues?api-version=7.0"
$responseGet = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $boardUri -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) }
$extensionFieldName = $responseGet.fields.rowField.referenceName

$uri = "https://$server/$collection/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$($id)?api-version=7.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) }
$SystemBoardLane = $result.fields.'System.BoardLane'
$KanbanRowLane = $result.fields.$extensionFieldName
$tags = $result.fields.'System.Tags' -split "\s*;\s*"
$state = $result.fields.'System.State'
$newBoardLane = 'CRM'
# Only update if change is needed (checks both System.BoardLane, not WEF_[guid]_KanbanRowLane)
if ($newBoardLane -and $newBoardLane -ne $SystemBoardLane) {
    echo "Before:" # from call above
    echo "  System.State:     $state"
    echo "  Tags:             $tags"
    echo "  System.BoardLane: $SystemBoardLane"
    echo "  KanbanRowLane:    $KanbanRowLane"
    echo ""
    echo "Changing $extensionFieldName to $newBoardLane"
    $body = @"
    [
        {
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/fields/$extensionFieldName",
            "from": null,
            "value": "$newBoardLane"
        }
    ]
"@
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $body -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) }
    # echo ""
    # echo "Change result:"
    # $result

    echo ""
    echo "Tweaking System.State"
    # select a new state from the other active ones that aren't the current one
    if ($state -ne 'Selected for Development') { $newState = 'Selected for Development'}
    if (-not $newState -and $state -ne 'On Hold') { $newState = 'On Hold'}
    if (-not $newState -and $state -ne 'Doing') { $newState = 'Doing'}
    echo "- change to $newState"
    $body = @"
[
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.State",
    "value": "$newState"
}
]
"@ 
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $body -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) }
    # echo ""
    # echo "Tweak result:"
    # $result

    echo "- change back to $state"
    $body = @"
[
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.State",
    "value": "$state"
}
]
"@ 
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Body $body -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) }
    # echo ""
    # echo "Tweak result:"
    # $result
    
    echo ""
    echo "After:"
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo) }
    $SystemBoardLane = $result.fields.'System.BoardLane'
    $KanbanRowLane = $result.fields.$extensionFieldName
    $tags = $result.fields.'System.Tags' -split "\s*;\s*"    
    echo "  System.State:     $state"
    echo "  Tags:             $tags"
    echo "  System.BoardLane: $SystemBoardLane"
    echo "  KanbanRowLane:    $KanbanRowLane"
    echo "  Expected lane:    $newBoardLane"
}
else {
    echo "No change needed: $SystemBoardLae and $KanbanRowLane already $newBoardLane"
}
```

```
PS F:\DevTeam\Project_Management\Projects\Jira_to_DevOps_Migration> .\update-Swimlane.ps1 12770
Before:
  System.State:     Selected for Development
  Tags:             CRM
  System.BoardLane:
  KanbanRowLane:    CRM

Changing WEF_5DD75A5340614097AADDCAFDEA91A637_Kanban.Lane to CRM

Tweaking System.State
- change to On Hold
- change back to Selected for Development

After:
  System.State:     Selected for Development
  Tags:             CRM
  System.BoardLane:
  KanbanRowLane:    CRM
  Expected lane:    CRM
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Swinlane rule`(Criteria option) is a new feature which announced in [sprint 221](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-221-update#swimlane-rules-is-generally-available)(May 9 2023), it's only available with the New Boards Hubs preview.

[image]

Currently, there is no this new boards hub feature on ADO sever 2022(i installed latest version Azure DevOps Server 2022.1)

[image]

I'm afraid it's currently not supported yet on ADO server 2022.

Edit: add powershell scrip to change the swimlane for the work item.

After you grant the swimlane field value `/WEF_39C0D7022xxx_Kanban.Lane`:

```
# change the parameters to yours 
Param(
   [string]$token = "PAT",
   [string]$baseurl = "http://testVM/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$project = "project1",
   [string]$workitemid = "1"
)

#$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User,$token)))
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$Header = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$uri = "$baseurl/$project/_apis/wit/workitems/$workitemid"+ "?api-version=7.0"

Write-Host $uri


# use target swinlane name for value
$body = @"
[
  {
    `"op`": `"add`",
    `"path`": `"/fields/WEF_39C0D70225034E42BD9EC83B788459CB_Kanban.Lane`",
    `"from`": null,
    `"value`": `"swimlane 3`"
  }
]
"@

Invoke-RestMethod $uri -Method PATCH -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json-patch+json" -Body $body
```

[image]

Eidt: If you move work items `across different state`, and into target swimlane, you need to add state field change in request body as well.

For example, work item in `New` state, and would like to change to `swimlane 3` in `Active` state.

[image]

Change the request body as below:

```
$body = @"
[
  {
    `"op`": `"add`",
    `"path`": `"/fields/WEF_39C0D70225034xxBD9EC83B778459CB_Kanban.Lane`",
    `"from`": null,
    `"value`": `"swimlane 3`"
  },
   {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.State",
    "value": "Active"
  }
]
"@
```

The `System.BoardLane` value will be automatically changed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Wade. That explains what I'm seeing. We'll have to wait for a future release of ADO Server to get built-in support for this.

Comment: In the meantime, I've written a PowerShell script using the REST API, using the technique described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58862961/azure-devops-rest-apis-for-swimlane to set work item WEF_[guid]_Kanban.Lane field, but though the updated value shows in the work item (via API GET), the card on the board does not move. 

Do you (or anyone else) have thoughts on that? (I tried to follow up on directly in that other topic, but I have too few reputation points.)

Comment: @RichardWells, the logic of the link is update the field of the target work item. I will share a powershell script which is working on my side, please have a check.

Comment: Thanks again, Wade.

That's substantially what my code does, though my PATCH call was using `"update"`. Changing `op` to `"add"` and adding `"from" : null` didn't change anything. 

I am seeing the expected update in the workitem properties, e.g. a GET of the workitem shows `WEF_5DD75A5340614097AADDCAFDEA91A637_Kanban.Lane=CRM`, but the card doesn't move on the board. The script doesn't affect the `System.BoardLane` property. And if I move a card manually on the board, only `System.BoardLane` changes.

Other suggestions?

Comment: When you move the workitem, will the state be changed as well? Try to move it but not change the work item for a check. If you change the state and set the swimlane, you need to add the field change in body as well.     {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.State",
    "value": "Active"
  }

Then the work item can be changed to active state, and to target swimlane in this column. I confirm the System.BoardLane will be updated automatically.

Comment: @wade-zhou-msft, the `WEF_5DD75A5340614097AADDCAFDEA91A637_Kanban.Lane` value never seems to be copied into the `System.BoardLane`. When I move the card manually between States, neither changes. When I move the card manually between lanes, only `System.BoardLane` changes. The `...Kanban.Lane` version never does.

Comment: @RichardWells, the value of `System.BoardLane` will be `automatically` changed. If you follow the above comment to add state change in request body together with `...CB_Kanban.Lane` field change, you will see the change of System.BoardLane. I will addd the appearance on the reply.

Comment: @wade-zhou-msft: even adding the tweak to `System.State` doesn't make this work for me. I wonder whether some Project or Board property is off.

Comment: Hi @RichardWells, please edit your description with more details so we can check what the problem is: 1. The work item and target swimlane in board. 2. Your powershell script. 3. The script execute result, any output or error?

Comment: @wade-zhou-msft: Description updated with script, output, and further questions about how Work Areas might factor into this situation.

Comment: As per the result, you are moving work items between different states in one script. However I don't find any request body which contains both `state` change, and `/fields/WEF..`. change together. Please double check my reply(new body in my reply) and fix the request body. It's recommended to work it out for two states change, and then refactor code to different state changes. Please firstly try my sample script, check if it works for one state(not have swimlane) to new state with target swimlane, will it work?

Comment: @wade-zhou-msft: Thanks for your follow-up suggestion. (Pardon my delay in replying, given local holidays, etc.) I tried added `state` into same request body with `WEF...` and that didn't work. I then copied your script, set the initial values, and it, too, does not work in my environment. 

I'm going to put this aside until we get the next update to Azure DevOps 2022.